# Three pulley system with middle pulley lower than the other two

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have a pulley system with 3 pulleys. Just wondering if this system is adding to the weight that is being lifted? It feels like it is increasing the weight, but i am not completely sure.

I do not want it increasing the weight, but i suspect it is.

Thanks

[image: my pulley system picture]

Comment: It might help to explain why you think it increases the weight? What physics principles are you using to come to this conclusion, and what are you unsure about in your understand / application of those principles?

Comment: I pull the weight down with my hand and it feels heavier with the middle pulley in place. Without the middle pulley it does not feel as heavy.

Comment: Could it be due to friction and/or inertia of the pulley? Ideally the middle pulley will have no effect.

Comment: It could be, just checking to see what other people with more knowledge of pulleys had to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all three pulleys are fixed to a wall or something you get some friction depending how easily  your pulley turns, and if it is heavy you need some force to turn it , so if the pulleys are light and work well it should not ad much, but it always adds a little.